# JSTL - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring

I'm going to start studying Spring Boot, so I quickly skimmed over Java EE so as not to be completely lost in learning Spring.

My question is about JSTL:
Is JSTL required to be used with Spring Boot?
Because I find it really ugly and old ...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is no, there is no need of using JSTL(JSP Standard Tag Library) with spring boot if you are not using JSP .